# (Build failed 'Xcodes output') The getter 'onChanged00' isn't defined for the class 'OTPTextField

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, debugging

I haven't worked on my app for 2 days and all of a sudden, when running the app, I get this error:
[debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qALkO.png)

I haven't touched the code and it was working fine 2 days ago.

The links in the error...

[otp_field file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lkp5.png)
[otp_field file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB3Jj.png)

...point to the *otp_field.dart* file(which I never opened), with the error being **The getter 'onChanged00' isn't defined for the class 'OTPTextField'.**

I'm not sure how this happened and can't seem to solve this. I updated the otp_field entry in the pubspec.yaml file, but this did not work either.
[pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEADY.png)

*(This also happens when I run using the android emulator)*

What am I missing here? Would be great if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.